# In how many way we can arrange 4 books on 7 different shelves - with no specific demandings?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, balls-in-bins

I was given an unconventional combinatorics question I was struggling with.
Suppose we have 4 books and 7 different bookshelves.
In how many ways the books can be arranged without loss of generality?

I can either put all 4 of them on 1 shelf, or either split each one in a different shelf. In a case such as that, how do I consider the shelves that can't be picked? how to sum the number of options I have left when I do pick $k < 4$  books on 1 shelf (which are arranged in $k!$ options) and left with 6 different shelves and $4-k$ books?

Best regards for the helpers.

Comment: Are the books identical or distinguishable? How about the shelves?

Comment: Honestly, the question doesnt say that specifically, but to my understanding all of the books and shelves are distiguishable

Comment: How could arranging books lead to loss of generality?

Comment: When arranging books on shelves, each book can be placed in at least $2$ different orientations, $4$ if you allow the back of the book to face away from you (and even more if you allow things to be a complete mess). Are we supposed to count them all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assume all books and shelves identical)

So you can have $(4,0,...,0)$ - 7 ways to choose which shelf this is

$(3,1,0,...,0)$ - 42 ways to choose the two shelves i.e. 6*7

$(2,2,0,...,0)$ - 7C2 ways to choose the two shelves (i.e. 6*7/2)

$(2,1,1,0,...,0)$ - 7*(6C2)

$(1,1,1,1,0,...,0)$ - 7C4

Now add all of these solutions together to get the final answer.

Comment: thank you for this answer. can you please elaborate on the line before the last one? (2,1,1,0,...,0) - 7*(6C2)

Comment: Sure. Let's say you have the 7 shelves. First you have to decide where to put the 2 books, there are 7 ways to do it. Then you have 6 shelves left and you would like to place two 1s, so there are 6C2 ways to do that.

Comment: after summing all those options i get 210 opptions. if i were to try to think about a general idea of n and k items that i want to order, doesnt it suppoed to be $\frac{(n+k)!}{k!n!}$ ? in this case it's 330

Answer (score 3):

In the following, I will assume that the books as well as the shelves are distinguishable.

The four books may be arranged in $4!$ ways.  We must choose how many books go on each of the seven shelves.  Let $x_j$, $1 \leq j \leq 7$, be the number of books placed on the $j$th shelf.  Then
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 = 4$$
is an equation in the nonnegative integers.  A particular solution of the equation corresponds to the placement of six addition signs in a row of four ones.  For instance,
$$+ + 1 1 + + + 1 + 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 0$, $x_2 = 0$, $x_3 = 2$, $x_4 = 0$, $x_5 = 0$, $x_6 = 1$, $x_7 = 1$, while
$$1 + + 1 + + 1 + + 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 1$, $x_2 = 0$, $x_3 = 1$, $x_4 = 0$, $x_5 = 1$, $x_6 = 0$, $x_7 = 1$. The number of such solutions is the number of ways we can place six addition signs in a row of four ones, which is
$$\binom{4 + 7 - 1}{7 - 1} = \binom{10}{6}$$
since we must select which six of the ten places required for four ones and six addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

Thus, the number of ways of placing four distinct books on seven shelves is 
$$4!\binom{10}{6}$$

Alternatively, we must arrange four distinct books and six identical dividers in a row - the dividers separate the books onto different shelves.  We can select the positions of the books in $\binom{10}{4}$ ways.  The books can be arranged in the selected positions in $4!$ ways.  The dividers must fill each of the remaining six positions.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{10}{4}4!$$
ways to arrange four distinct books on seven shelves.

Comment: Very informing and elegant!
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Each book can be put into $7$ different book shelves. So the total number of ways is $7^4.$

Comment: Certainly whenever there is more than one book on a shelf, there are multiple ways to place them (even without counting orientations of individual books, just permutation of the books).

Comment: That's correct @Marc van Leeuwen. But I think OP ignores the ordering of books in a particular shelf.